# Would a native speaker ever say 'haven't not done sth'?

Tags: grammar-myths

In an English subtitle translated from other language, I saw such a sentence:

> I haven't not thought about that a little.

What the speaker actually meant was 'I have thought about that.'(**Can I use an emphatic 'do' between 'I' and 'have'?**)

I know that double negatives produce an affirmative. Yet I have never seen any sentence like this before, which seems weird and grammatically wrong to me. **Would a native speaker ever say 'haven't not done sth'?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so except some weird context like

> 'Have you thought about it?'

and then

> 'Well...I haven't *not* thought about it.'

I can imagine there could be some kind of context for this, but it's rare.

Of course, people do say like 'I haven't thought of nothing.'

Anyway, I suspect that subtitle just erred in repeating the 'not'. Or maybe you provide the context?

Comment: People often say 'I haven't/didn't/won't/don't (etc) not done something', at least in British English, when they want to emphasise the absence of a deliberate omission or failure to do something. Emphasis in speech on the 'not'. Not really 'weird'. For example: Person A: I understand you're not speaking to Mary. Person B: I'm not _not_ speaking to her, I've just been too busy to call her'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey It's kind of hard for me to comprehend 'to emphasise the absence of a deliberate omission or failure to do something'. Not so sure about what that means.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You mean it's actually an negative, so it means 'I haven't thought about that'? The point is, the 'not do sth' is not deliberate? I may misunderstand the dialogue.

Comment: Michael H's Person B is not _deliberately_ avoiding speaking to Mary, it just happens that they haven't spoken to her. In your sentence, it's the addition of 'a little' that makes it sound really weird.

Comment: @KateBunting Maybe it means 'not that I haven't thought **even a little/the least** about that'?